# User-defined function with bind params

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using the Postgres upsert example. I can get it to work as shown in the example but I need to make the function call be dynamic. The function is

```
CREATE TABLE db (a INT PRIMARY KEY, b TEXT);

CREATE FUNCTION merge_db(key INT, data TEXT) RETURNS VOID AS
$$
BEGIN
LOOP
    UPDATE db SET b = data WHERE a = key;
    IF found THEN
        RETURN;
    END IF;
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO db(a,b) VALUES (key, data);
        RETURN;
    EXCEPTION WHEN unique_violation THEN
    END;
END LOOP;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I can get it to work this way:

```
SELECT merge_db(1, 'david');
SELECT merge_db(1, 'dennis');
```

But I would like to do something like:

```
SELECT merge_db($1,$2);
```

Is this possible? I know I can do this by concatenating strings but I would like to prepare my statement and use bind params.

Comment: Where are you trying to call `merge_db`? From a client program? From another PostgreSQL function?

Comment: A client program. I want to use like I would use "INSERT INTO table VALUES($1,$2)" then exec the statement with dynamic values.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why I didn't think to try this before but here's the answer:

```
CREATE TABLE db (a INT PRIMARY KEY, b TEXT);

CREATE FUNCTION merge_db(INT, TEXT) RETURNS VOID AS
$$
BEGIN
LOOP
    UPDATE db SET b = $2 WHERE a = $1;
    IF found THEN
        RETURN;
    END IF;
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO db(a,b) VALUES ($1, $2);
        RETURN;
    EXCEPTION WHEN unique_violation THEN
    END;
END LOOP;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

With that you can use

```
SELECT merge_db($1, $2)
```

Comment: That function is not different to your previous one. The name of the parameter is only a placeholder (`$1` and `key` reference the same thing) and you should have been able to call the original version in just the same way.